# Convert msxml.xmhttp code for 64 bit version of excel vba

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I have been using the following function in Excel VBA with my 32 bit machine and recently upgraded to a 64bit machine and the 64 bit version of Excel 2013.  It still works somewhat, but only downloads a part of the http code.  I have looked all over the place and I cannot find anything to suggest how to fix this;  would really appreciate some help in getting this to work again.
Thanks
Dave

```
Function SaveWebFile(ByVal vWebFile As String, ByVal vLocalFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, i As Long, vFF As Long, oResp() As Byte
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, False 'Open socket to get the website
    oXMLHTTP.Send 'send request
    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    oResp = oXMLHTTP.responseBody 'Returns the results as a byte array
    vFF = FreeFile
    If Dir(vLocalFile) <> "" Then Kill vLocalFile
    Open vLocalFile For Binary As #vFF
    Put #vFF, , oResp
    Close #vFF
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I did not get your question!

Comment: You mean you don't understand what I am asking for?

Comment: The above code works perfectly when I run it with excel 2010 32 bit, but when I run it with excel 2013 64 bit, I get a truncated version of the html code...

Comment: I believe this has something to do with ie11 vs ie8.  Whereas the particular website allowed me to fetch web pages after I had logged in with my password while using ie8, it does not seem to do so when using ie11.

Comment: Definitely an issue with ie11 not passing cookies to the website.  Anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried oXMLHttp.responseText ?

Comment: this could be the comment not the answer